# Running Node app with Spy.js does not recognize variables defined with let

Tags: node.js, profiling

I'm trying to run a simple Node app that has a global variable defined with `let` and initialized in a function and then used in another (something like the following code)

```
let some_variable;

a.doSomething(value => {
    some_variable = value;
    doSomethingElse();
});

function doSomethingElse() {
    // This is where I get the error
    console.log(some_variable);
}
```

When running that Node app from command line or from WebStorm, it all goes well but when trying to run it with [Spy.js](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/spy-js.html), it doesn't recognize `some_variable` and says `some_variable is not defined`.

I tried running with `--harmony` flag but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

When changing `let some_variable` to `var some_variable` it seems to work, but that would require me to change the code of my entire app just to get it profiled by Spy.js which doesn't sound like a good idea.

Any ideas how to make Spy.js recognize `let` variables? Am I missing a simple configuration flag?

(Node version is 6.10.1)